# Should we have tags "ashkenazi" and "jews"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I added a new tag [ashkenazi](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ashkenazi) for [a question I posted](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/14450/how-to-interpret-my-having-ethnicities-inconsistent-with-my-parents). As many of you know, people of Ashkenazi descent have special issues with interpreting DNA relatedness, due to their ancestors' endogamy.

I'm now second guessing whether the tag is needed, since we already have [jews](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jews). (While Ashkenazim are the largest population of Jews, especially in English-speaking countries, they are not the only ones.)

Should we get rid of [ashkenazi](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ashkenazi) or make it a synonym for [jews](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jews)? I have the ability to create tags but not to create tag synonyms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about [jewish](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jewish) (which we already have, so don't needs Jews) and [endogamy](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/endogamy) (to handle the broader topic of endogamy?

From the [ISOGG Wiki](https://isogg.org/wiki/Endogamy):

> Examples of endogamous groups include Jews, Polynesians, Low German
>   Mennonites, the Amish, Acadians or Cajuns (French settlers in what is
>   now Nova Scotia, Canada), French Canadians, people from many Arab
>   countries, people from Newfoundland and people from many islands.
>   Endogamy is also a problem in early Colonial American populations.

Comment: I agree that `jewish` and `endogamy` are sufficient. I'd like to see `Ashkenazi` as a tag synonym for `jewish`, but those with the power to create tag synonyms can decide.

Comment: I don't hav the rep to suggest the synonym, unfortunately. Will ping moderators in chat.

Comment: @Ellen I've made Ashkenazi a synonym of Jewish now